# Reconstruct ggplot2 boxplots given dataframe with relevant columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am wondering what is the idiomatic approach for constructing a ggplot2 boxplot given precomputated values for each boxplot

```
> df
    base p10 p90 lower_quartile     mean median upper_quartile
1      1  32  35             33 33.63740     34             34
2      2  32  35             33 33.77753     34             35
3      3  32  36             33 33.89361     34             35
4      4  33  36             33 33.89691     34             35
5      5  32  35             33 33.85145     34             35
6      6  35  37             37 36.48259     37             37
```

Attempting to draw these plots with

```
ggplot(df, aes(base)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = p10,
                   lower = lower_quartile,
                   middle = median,
                   upper = upper_quartile,
                   ymax = p90),
               stat = "identity")
```

does not give the desired plots. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what base represents in your data.frame but in order to do it correctly your x-axis is supposed to be discrete (to show the different boxplots). Then for the y axis you need a `ymin`, a `lower`, a `middle`, an `upper` and a `ymax` which you have provided. The x-axis is the variable that is used to plot the different boxplots. So, if you turn it into a factor then it works:

```
library(ggplot2)
#I have added base as factor
ggplot(df, aes(factor(base))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = p10,
                   lower = lower_quartile,
                   middle = median,
                   upper = upper_quartile,
                   ymax = p90),
               stat = "identity")
```

Output:

[image]

And this way it works.